# Multiplechoice widget with really big lsit

Tags: django, django-admin

In my model Person can have more than one partner, so the ManyToMany Model is the only answer (this has to be ManyToMany for other reasons, so please don't think about changing it).

If I use default widget i got a list of all persons with selected one, two maybe three persons (which are partners of Person). 
It would be ok, if the Person list is about 10-100 - and it works on test database. But my prod database has 10.000 persons or more, so the ModelMultipleChoice widget would be filled with 10.000 records, and finding the correct partner will last ages, and memory usage isn't trivial.

I need only to see names of partners with possibility to unset it from person, and some possibility to add new just typing name. The best solution is to show listbox with filtered names after typing three or four first letters, but any solution would be great.

With forms it would be easier, but I need it in admin, so I'd like to use django admin standards.

Comment: Use what Twitter and Facebook are using for people searching .. Typeahead is the only answer if you are willing to do some javascript scripting. Otherwise, your user should search --> then pick one of the results and you sort them by their relevance.

Comment: Great, but is is possible in django admin?

Comment: You will need to create your own JavaScript code in order to interact with a backend that do the filtering for you, and of course create your own widget. OR you can use this https://github.com/sjrd/django-ajax-selects